# cannot connect to azure postresql - Username should be in <username@hostname> format

Tags: postgresql, azure, sqlalchemy, ckan

I'm trying to use azure PostgreSQL for CKAN (ckan.org) 
CKAN is using http://www.sqlalchemy.org/ for database connection.

A connection string looks like this:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://scott:tiger@myhost.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/mydatabase')
```

syntax is:

```
postgresql://username:password@hostname:5432/databasename
```

When trying to connect to azure postgresql I get this error:

> FATAL:  Invalid Username specified. Please check the Username and
>   retry connection. The Username should be in username@hostname format.

If I try to use the username format like this:

```
postgresql://scott@myhost:tiger@myhost.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/mydatabase
```

Then I get:

> invalid port number: "tiger@myhost.postgres.database.azure.com:5432"

Has anyone solved this?

Answer (score 2):

The invalid port number is caused by the `@` in the user name.

The connection url should look like this:

```
postgresql://scott%40myhost:tiger@myhost.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/mydatabase
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending Allan Kristensen's answer, you'll end up with problem if you're using the datastore extension (Bundled with CKAN Core).

Looking at the codebase of CKAN the problem is in https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/555e0960c43d0ca86066b1954e5c94aad565baa7/ckanext/datastore/backend/postgres.py#L1592 (or https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/ckan-2.6.4/ckanext/datastore/plugin.py#L200 if you're running 2.6.5 or less)

Thus, when CKAN queries the database with `SELECT has_table_privilege('scott@myhost', '_foo', 'INSERT')` it's fail, as there's no user named `scott@myhost`. Azure is doing something funky with the usernames, as if you ask the database to list the users, you'll see that the database thinks your username is `scott` (Atleast that's what it did for me...)

One possible, hackish, fix is:

```
sed -i '' 's/read_connection_user = sa_url.make_url(self.read_url).username/read_connection_user = split(sa_url.make_url(self.read_url).username, "@")[0]/' /srv/app/src/ckan/ckanext/datastore/plugin.py
sed -i '' 's/import sys/import sys\nfrom string import split/' /srv/app/src/ckan/ckanext/datastore/plugin.py
```

The above works for 2.6.5. Substitute the file path with `/srv/app/src/ckanext/datastore/backend/postgres.py` if you're running 2.7+

The above should work until upstream have found a proper fix.

Comment: In 2.8 the issue you describe in your answer will occur as well. My connections in general seem completely fine though, it's just in this check that the datastore does.